# General formula for factorial moments of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a random variable that follows $X \sim \text{Bin(n,p)}$, one knows that $\text{Pr(X=k)} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{k-n}$, and using this one can compute the factorial moment,

$$\begin{align}
E[(X)_r]=E[x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1)] &= E\left[\frac{x!}{(x-k)!}\right]\\
&=\sum \frac{x!p(x)}{(x-k)!}\\
&=\sum \frac{x!n!}{x!(x-k)!(n-x)!}p^xq^{n-x}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}p^k \sum \frac{(n-k)!}{(x-k)!(n-x)!}p^{x-k}q^{n-x}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}p^k
\end{align}$$

However, is there a general expression for a factorial moment of the form, $E[(X)_r(1-X)_l]$. I tried deriving it using the approach written out above, but got nowhere. Chucking it into mathematica gives me expressions involving hypergeometric functions, which sort of makes sense since the pochammer symbol appears in the definition for the hypergeometric function, but I was wondering if there was a clean expression of the form given above?